# How to update relational types in Graphql

Tags: neo4j, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-mutation, neo4j-graphql-js

I am new to Graphql and I want to update relational types, but I have no idea how to do it.

My type definitions are as following:

```
type User {
    email: String!
    username: String!
    password: String!
    registered_at: Date!
    role: String!
    Questionnaire: [Questionnaire!]! @relationship(type: "has_questionnaire", direction: OUT)
}

type Questionnaire {
    User: [User!]! @relationship(type: "has_questionnaire", direction: IN)
    id: ID!
    ClosedQuestions: [Answer!]! @relationship(type: "has_answered", direction: OUT)
    OpenQuestions: [BigInt]
}

type Answer {
    Questionnaire: Questionnaire! @relationship(type: "has_answered", direction: IN)
    id: ID!
    component: String!
    scope: String!
    answer: String!
    answered_at: Date!
}
```

1. How would I write my mutation if I want to update the OpenQuestions list from a specific Questionnaire (id) from a specific user (username). My attempt was the following:

```
mutation {
    updateUsers(
        where: {
            username: „Kilian“
            id: „Project 1“      ##This id refers to the Questionnaire id
        }
        update: {
            OpenQuestions: [2, 3]
        }
    ) {
        users {
            Questionnaire {
                OpenQuestions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

/\ But this does not work...

2. One step further/deeper: How would I write my mutation if I want to update a specific answer (id) within a specific questionnaire from a specific user?

Many thanks for your help! ✌️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update nested properties, you need to add the updated data and filtering on those properties within the `where` input

To achieve what you want, you can run a query similar to this:

```
mutation {
  updateUsers(
    where: {
      username: "Kilian"
    }
    update: {
      Questionnaire: {
        where: { node: { id: "Project 1" } }
        update: { node: { OpenQuestions: [2, 3] } }
      }
    }
  ) {
    users {
      Questionnaire {
        OpenQuestions
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the query above, we are updating only users with `username` Kilian. Of those users, we are updating the relationship `Questionnaire`. From these related nodes, we are filtering only those with id `Project 1`. From these filtered nodes we update the `OpenQuestions` property.

Note that we need to add `node` to nested `where` and `update`. This is because we can update the relationship properties (if there were any) using `edge`.

To update a specific answer, you can follow the same pattern inside the nested update something like:

```
...
update: { node: { 
     OpenQuestions: [2, 3]
     ClosedQuestions: {
       where: { 
          id: "answerId"
        }
       update: { node: { answer: "my updated answer" } }
  } 
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It looks very correct but it still throws an error. So there is no error when compiling, but after I send the request in my graphql sandbox I get the following error:  

"There is no procedure with the name `apoc.do.when` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed." --

Any ideas?  

I will mark your answer as correct/closed soon. :)

Comment: To use @neo4j/graphql you need to have apoc enabled in your database https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/#:~:text=APOC%20Full%20can%20be%20installed,see%20the%20%22Installed%22%20message.
Please make sure it is installed and check if the error persists

Comment: Many thanks. It works now perfectly!

For others: You can run a neo4j instance and need the apoc plugin installed - via docker just type in the terminal:

"docker run \
    -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 \
    -v $PWD/data:/data -v $PWD/plugins:/plugins \
    --name neo4j-apoc \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config=true \
    -e NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=\[\"apoc\"\] \
    neo4j:4.0"

See https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures or (link in comment before) for more information.